# Want to use UIPageControl / UIScrollView as a showcase for an array of photos

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I would have thought that this would have been a trivial question, but it truly isn't. I've been keeping an eye out for one online for resources relating to a UIPageControl / UIScrollView, for months but I haven't found anything. There has to be something out there because I feel like this is such a common thing to do! I've seen it in so many apps!

What I want to do is have a project that's just like this one https://github.com/GalacticMegacorp/GMCPagingScrollView, however when I click on an image item, I want a fullscreen UIPageViewController with all of the images to show up. I feel like this is probably a very standard thing for showing products for a retail app, like Fab

Answer (score 0):

You should make a collectionView that shows all of the images it sounds like